# Weird bug color text in dark mode compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Hi I'm new to compose and I'm trying to debug this weird text color bug

Color should be white and it's like a grey dark which seems to disappear and set white color once I scroll them out of sight and scroll back to the previous positions.

Pretty sure someone had this error before, am I missing something? Why does this error happen?

Edit: This only happens when my phone has dark mode activated. If I deactivate it and set false/true in TodoTheme(...) everything works as expected.

Most simple code to repro:

```
setContent {
    TodoTheme {
        TodoScreen()
    }
}

@Composable
fun TodoScreen(
) {
    val text = "This is a big text that will make color change and won't be very much visible for the user, why does this happen?"
    LazyColumn(){
        items(listOf(text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text,text)) { string ->
            Text(text = string, color = MaterialTheme.colors.onSurface)
        }
    }
}
```

Colors are the one by default (I don't think this is a color problem):

```
val LightThemeColors = lightColors(
    primary = Purple700,
    primaryVariant = Purple800,
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    secondary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.Black,
    background = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color.Black,
    surface = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.Black,
    error = Red800,
    onError = Color.White
)

val DarkThemeColors = darkColors(
    primary = Purple300,
    primaryVariant = Purple600,
    onPrimary = Color.Black,
    secondary = Color.Black,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    background = Color.Black,
    onBackground = Color.White,
    surface = Color.Black,
    onSurface = Color.White,
    error = Red300,
    onError = Color.Black
)
```

Here's a video that you'll be able to watch exactly what's happening. This is on a Redmi Note 8 Pro.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwVO62NXCQU

And the image:
[image]

Comment: please add your composable cell code and your theme with colors

Comment: Added @Philip , also I just noticed that this only happens when my phone has dark mode activated. If I deactivate it this works as expected.

Comment: please make a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), now code has some "Unresolved references", like `TodoStateTest`. And remove as much code as you can to localise the problem

Comment: What is exactly the text with the issue?

Comment: Added video. The issue is that it doesn't render at first the text with the white color only when the phone is with dark mode activated.  @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Updated code and video @Philip

Comment: Hi @Barrufet, if you are using a Redmi phone and only have this issue when dark mode is enabled in the phone, go to Settings -> Display -> More Dark Mode Options and then from the app list just uncheck your app to see if it works properly.

Comment: Woah this solved the issue!! @Kartik Post this answer and I'll give it as valid. Btw if you know how to make your app unchecked by default then post it also

Comment: Sadly I don't have a device with dark mode and on the emulator seems working fine. If it reproducible on such simple code, it's probably a bug of compose, I suggest you reporting it to [google issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=612128&template=1253476) mentioning your device and android version.

Comment: @Barrufet added as an answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```

You can add this line in the theme used for the application and it will not override the app in dark mode even when force dark mode is enabled

**ORIGINAL ANSWER BELOW**

If you are using a Redmi/Xiaomi phone and only have this issue when dark mode is enabled in the phone, go to Settings -> Display -> More Dark Mode Options and then from the app list just uncheck your app to see if it works properly

But I am yet to find a solution for this thing turning on by default. I will update this answer once I find that too.

[image: Select Dark Mode From Settings]

[image: Select More Dark Mode Options]

[image: Find your app from the individual apps list and turn off the toggle]

Comment: Hey man, you just saved me so much time. I would never expect this to be the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Just saying, this answer would work the same with Accompanist VerticalPager or HorizontalPager with text in it, as both pagers are powered from LazyColumn for VerticalPager and LazyRow for HorizontalPager. If you have problems scrolling pager with text in it and the text color is wrong in dark mode, do as the answer said. Thanks btw Kartik!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try the following: Inside the `TodoRow` composable, instead of setting the background of the `Row` with the modifier, wrap the row in a `Surface` and do not set the text color. As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes) states:

> When setting the background color of any elements, prefer using a Surface to do this, as the **Surface sets an appropriate content color**. Be wary of direct Modifier.background() calls, which do not set an appropriate content color.

Does that help?

Comment: Saw other post with a similar answer, sadly this didn't help. I've updated the code to the most simple one to repro it and a video but I think this is a device issue and nothing related to compose and/or my code.

Answer (score 0):

delete themes file in dark values,
and remove the

```
<item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/red900</item>
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/anyColor</item>
<item name="colorSecondary">@color/anyColor</item>
<item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/anyColor</item>
<item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/anyColor</item>
```

these item colors from your themes file