# How to correctly set the ForceDarkAllowed to false in jetpack compose app

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-dark-theme

I want to set the **[ForceDarkAllowed](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#disable-force-dark)** to false in jetpack compose app.
I've found the information about the flag in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68651348/weird-bug-color-text-in-dark-mode-compose). There are 2 ways mentioned how this flag can be set. None of them seems to be straight forward when jetpack compose is used.
I have jetpack compose android app where I use Material3 design and I don't have the *styles.xml* file at all. So I can't add the

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="...">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>
</style>
```

there.

Second method allows me to set it on the View object using the [setForceDarkAllowed](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForceDarkAllowed(boolean)) method. I'm not advanced in jetpack compose, but I don't see how I could get the View object in my project.

So how to set that flag properly in project that is fully written using jetpack compose and MaterialTheme3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Theme.kt use:

> LocalView.current.isForceDarkAllowed = true // or false

or you can use it with other views:

```
val view = remember { View(this) }
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
    view.isForceDarkAllowed = true // or false
    onDispose { }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it allows me to set the force dark allowed variable.
Still, I was hoping it will help me solve the incorrect text color issue on real devices described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77103964/text-color-is-incorrect-in-dark-mode-on-real-device
Unfortunatelly it did not.

Comment: Well, finally it worked, when I connected this with the <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>in style file.